# FFmpeg h265 encode->decode, c++

Tags: c++, encoding, ffmpeg

Hi I already have some working encoding and direct decoding code for h264. 
I'm trying to adapt the code to work with h265 but I'm doing something wrong with the decoding since I always get the error message:

```
[hevc @ 0x78eca0] PPS id out of range: 0
[hevc @ 0x78eca0] Error parsing NAL unit #0.
```

Decoding Init:

```
decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H265);

ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);
ctx->extradata = NULL;
ctx->width = 400;
ctx->height = 256;
ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

avcodec_open2(ctx,decoder,NULL);
```

Encoding, seems ok, since I only work with small videos I only get a single nal :

```
x265_nal* nals;
unsigned int i_nals;

int ret = x265_encoder_encode(m_x265Encoder, &nals, &i_nals, m_picIn, m_picOut);

AVPacket avpkt;
av_init_packet(&avpkt);
avpkt.size = nals[0].sizeBytes;
avpkt.data = nals[0].payload;
AVFrame* frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

int got=0;
avcodec_decode_video2(ctx,frame,&got,&avpkt);
```

Can anybody help me with this?

br
Mike

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

actually I found a working solution, it's not the best code and was mainly for testing, in the end x265 was just to slow on the cpu and couldn't keep up for live streaming:

```
    AVFrame* avpic = av_frame_alloc();
    avpic->pts = msg.TimeStampCapture;
    avpic->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    avpic->width = _dstFrameWidth;
    avpic->height = _dstFrameHeight;

    AVPicture tmppic;
    avpicture_fill(&tmppic, pSrc, _rawFormat, _srcFrameWidth, _srcFrameHeight);
    int err_sws = sws_scale(pSWSContext, tmppic.data, tmppic.linesize, 0, _srcFrameHeight, avpic->data, avpic->linesize);

    int ret = av_image_alloc(avpic->data, avpic->linesize, avpic->width, avpic->height,AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,8 );

    // Using scale Context to create avpic fore video2 encode
    SwsContext* pSWSContext = sws_getContext(_srcFrameWidth, _srcFrameHeight, _rawFormat, _dstFrameWidth, _dstFrameHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BILINEAR , 0, 0, 0);

    sws_freeContext(pSWSContext);
    int got_packet;
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
    pkt.size = 0;

    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(_ectx,&pkt,avpic,&got_packet);
    //count ++;
    msg.pts = pkt.pts;
    msg.dts = pkt.dts;
    msg.count = count++;
    msg.flags = pkt.flags;


    nEncodedSize = pkt.size;


    /// Decoder test
    AVPacket avpkt;
    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
    avpkt.data = pkt.data;
    avpkt.size = pkt.size;
    avpkt.pts = pkt.pts;
    avpkt.dts = pkt.dts;
    avpkt.flags = pkt.flags;
    avpkt.stream_index = pkt.stream_index;
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();


    int got_picture = 0;
    avcodec_decode_video2(m_cc,frame,&got_picture,&avpkt)

    av_frame_free(&avpic);
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
```